# Groups on the set $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm self-studying abstract algebra from Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra and I'm have a problem understanding how he obtains his answer for ch.3 exercise B2.

For the following, we need to determine whether it is commutative, associative, whether it has an identity element, and whether it has an inverse. From there, we need to tell whether it is a group (and if it is, if it is abelian):

$$(a, b) \cdot (c, d) = (ac, bc + d)$$ on the set $${(x, y) \in \Bbb R \times \Bbb R: x \neq 0}.$$

He proves that it is associative this way:

$$(a, b) \cdot [(c, d) \cdot (e, f)] = (a, b) \cdot (ce, de + f) = (ace, bce + de + f)$$

$$[(a, b) \cdot (c, d)] \cdot (e, f) = (ac, bc + d) \cdot (e, f) = (ace, bce + de + f).$$

Is there a particular method that this is solved by? Is there a name for it? Please give me info or resources if you can.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What are you asking?  This computation shows that the two expressions are equal, which is the definition of associativity.

Comment: I mainly don't understand how it was computed. If the computation were to be expanded, how would it be done?

Comment: In the first line, the second multiplication is done first (as indicated by the square brackets), yielding $(ce,de+f)$.  Then the remaining multiplication is done.  In the second line, the first multiplication is done first, yielding $(ac,bc+d)$, and then the other multiplication.

Comment: For anyone curious about where this operation comes from, and why it should be associative with identity, note that it is equivalent to matrix multiplication on the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}x & 0 \\ y & 1\end{pmatrix}$, i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \\ b & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}c & 0 \\ d & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}ac & 0 \\ bc+d & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Slade: I just thought about that, that you will find this group as a subgroup of invertible real matrices. Wanted to figure it out myself, but had no paper and pencil in reach and then saw your  nice comment :) Can one broaden this result: If you have amy group law on the set $K^n$, where each component of the operation is given by some polynomial. Can we realize this group as a subgroup of invertible mxm-matrices? If yes, does the smallest $m$ possible relate to $n$ (and maybe to the degree of the polynomials occuring in the definition of the operation)?

Comment: In general we will have $m>n$ by the simple observation that $(K,+)$ is not a subgroup of $K^*$. we have the famous $$(K,+) \cong \begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @MooS This question is complicated slightly by the fact that this is only a group law when restricted to $K^\times \times K$.  I don't think it's true that every quasi-affine algebraic group of finite type over a field can be embedded in a matrix group, but I'm sure there are lots of interesting results of this sort—it's just not my area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done like this
$$(a,b)\dot[(c,d)\cdot (e,f)]=(a,b)\cdot (ce,de+f)$$
by definition, next
$$(a,b)\cdot (ce,de+f)= (a[ce],b[ce]+[de+f])=(ace,bce+de+f)$$
And similarly for the other, the definition is used iteratively. Just keep in mind what the definition says about the various parts.